# Php input value

Tags: php

I am trying to understand this syntax `<?=$value;?>` in php, **For example:**

```
<input type="text" name="user" value="<?=$_POST["user"];?>" id="user">
```

As i understand it is not some xml syntax becouse the file has to be **.php** file, Also the:

```
<? ?> // short opening tags in the <?=$_POST["user"];?> syntax
```

Is working even if i set **short_open_tag = Off**, If anyone can please help me understand this syntax and how doe's it working with the **short_open_tag = Off**, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Comment: `short_open_tag` is depreciated..please dont use that

Comment: it's an implicit PHP echo (example #2, number 3) http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php - see notes for short open tags

Comment: Is there an alternative for the sort_open_tag?

Comment: I think that means `<? echo $_POST["user"]; ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<?=$value;?>` is short-hand syntax for `<?php echo $value; ?>`.

As to why it works even with `short_open_tags` turned off; are you using `PHP >=5.4.0`? If so,  that's expected; it's always available. See [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag).

Comment: Thank nyou Michael, this is the link i was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
<input type="text" name="user" value="<?=$_POST['user'];?>" id="user" />
```

You forget `"` .

And `<?=$_POST['user'];?>` is the simple and short form of `<?php echo $_POST['user']; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" name="user" value=<?=$_POST["user"];?> id="user">

value=<?=$_POST["user"];?>
```

Means the value you entered in the input field with name 'user' and submitted.

Answer (score 1):

`<? ?>` is the same as `<?php ?>`. Since they are inserting a php value `$_POST["user"]` into the Form they are using the `<? ?>`